# Problem with data table selection and how to access var outside of repeating block

Tags: jsf

I have a screen that I show some records with datatable from primefaces

enter code here

1) In my bean, I have two lists, the first one I enter the records returning from the database, 
   and the other is used to store the selected screen items.

```
@Getter @Setter
private List<RecorsDTO> recordsList;

@Getter @Setter
private List<RecorsDTO> selectedRecordsList;
```

In another screen, I show the IDs selected in the previous screen, for that I used the repeat 
function of primefaces

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText value="#{selectedRecords.id}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

The problem here is that it only shows the first list item, for example:

Records Selected in first screen:  100, 101

Records displayed on second screen:  100

2) I also need to show other attributes of the List, but these outside the repeat block, for example:

```
      <h:panelGroup>
          <h:outputText value="#{selectedRecords.id}" />
      </h:panelGroup>

  </ui:repeat>
```

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText value="#{selectedRecords.nome}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

The problem here is that I can't access var = selectedRecords out of the repeating block, I tried to use
the dataGrid component to have is a var visible inside and outside the repeating block, but it didn't work either.

Any ideas that might help me in this case?

Comment: Please edit your question and try to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your feedback, I managed to solve the problem as below:

1) This issue was related to duplicate records, my Bean myBBean.selectedRecordsList was returning two records
equal (100, 100) and then within the repeat block he would perform a sort of "DISTINCT" and display only a record (100).

2) The var = selected records that I defined within block repetition are valid only within it and for access outside of
repetition block, I failed not to mention the index as it is a list as below

value="#{myBBean.selectedRecordslist.get(0).name}"